# NSToolbarItem Segue Popover using Storyboards in Xcode 7 beta 3

Tags: segue, swift2, nstoolbaritem, nsstoryboard, xcode7-beta3

I'm trying to create a popover from a NSToolbarItem using storyboards. I'm using OS X 10.11 beta 3 and Xcode beta 3. This is my setup:

[image]

before beta 3 I simply placed a view controller near the window controller, then dragged from the toolbar item to the controller and selected the segue way to be a popover. I then ran the program and it would work automatically no problem.

On beta 3 this is what happens after I click on the toolbar item at run time:

[image]

did something change in swift? do I have to manually implement something there? or is there a bug?

Ps. I tried placing a button in the Window Controller's Content View controller (The "Hi" button in my example), then created a segue way from that button to another view controller with popover and that works fine.